# powershell parameters command line menu

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I wish to create a script which accepts input from the command line and based on the first value, it then determines the next parameters on offer.

Such as to determine if you are to do a single Run or a Batch run for a Password change operation:

./script.ps1 -singleMODE -UserName  -Password

./script.ps1 -batchMODE -filename

What i am confused about whilst learning Powershell is what this is? I have looked at Parameters and can read them into variables from command line...but what i want as above has some logic and i am a bit lost. Can someone give me a nudge as to what this is called....and then i can continue my googling! :)

I am thinking somehow i combine Params and Functions so it flicks to different blocks...but i am guessing

any help appreciated! :)

cheers

Comment: You are probably looking for [parameter sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need are Parameter Sets

This is a demo with a function but it works just as well with a script (just put the param block at the top.)

```
function Demo {
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Funk')][switch]$Funk,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Rock')][switch]$Rock,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Funk')][string]$WriteFunk,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Rock')][string]$WriteRock
    )
    if($Funk){
        foreach ($C in $WriteFunk.ToCharArray()){
            $N = 0..15 | Get-Random
            Write-Host $C -ForegroundColor $N -BackgroundColor $(15-$N) -NoNewline
        }
        Write-Host ''
    }
    if($Rock){
        Write-Host $WriteRock -ForegroundColor Gray -BackgroundColor DarkGray
    }
}

Demo -Funk -WriteFunk "Melt your brain"
Demo -Rock -WriteRock "Riders on the storm"
```

Comment: Thanks - that is awesome! And the code example gave me a smile!!! :)....Actually if i try and use that code snippet outside of the Function...i get an Ambigous Parameter Set error. Within the Function it is perfect

Comment: that would be because I switched from metal to rock and disco to funk halfway through writing it and forgot to switch all the variables, it's fixed now

Comment: Thanks!!!! I have been able to adapt it successfully....well so far anyway. cheers

Comment: no problem, also note that you don't need to use the first argument as a dedicated switch, it is smart enough to know which set you are in by the variables that are used. I recommend investigating $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName